# SharePoint 2013 Enterprise Search Errors

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search, sharepoint-search, sharepoint-farm

Issue:
When performing any type of search whether that be from the Enterprise Search Center or from Query Rules to test a query, the page results in an error.

Error on Manage Query Rules and Enterprise Search pages:  Search has encountered a problem that prevents results from being returned.

Farm background:
New environment being stood up.
All servers are running Windows Server 2012 R2 with 24GB RAM
The database servers 2 running MS SQL Server 2012 R2 with 32 GB ram
We are using windows authentication as well as ADFS.  All user UPN's have been updated in Active Directory to the domain UPN.
SSL is implemented using standard port 443.

Topology:
2 WFEs
--Search Query Processing Component
--Search Admin Component
3 Application Servers
--Search Crawler Component
--Search Content Processing Component
--Search Analytics Processing
--Search Index Partition
2 DBs

Non-SP Servers:
1 Office Web Apps
1 ADFS
1 Workflows
1 proxy

Search does crawl successfully and there are approximately 400k items in the index.  Seems to be related only to the Query Process.

ULS log shows:
    Name=Request (POST:https://thehive.xxxx.org:443/search/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery) b613bb9c-fc4a-a020-6d41-0a96138145fb

```
Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0e.t|adfs provider|spadm@xxxxxxx.local, ClaimsCount=11    b613bb9c-fc4a-a020-6d41-0a96138145fb

Name=Timer Job SchedulingUnpublish  b613bb9c-3c4e-a020-6d41-01bfb551c3a0
SearchServiceApplicationProxy::GetQueryParameterSpecification--Proxy Name:Search Application Proxy EndPoint: http://webserver1:32843/04a32ef4861448aa873b85a2a67b1b20/SearchService.svc b613bb9c-fc4a-a020-6d41-0a96138145fb

SearchServiceApplicationProxy::GetChannel--Channel Creation time: 3.9996 b613bb9c-fc4a-a020-6d41-0a96138145fb

WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://web1:32843/04a32ef4861448aa873b85a2a67b1b20/SearchService.svc' Channel: 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.ISearchServiceApplication' Action: 'http://tempuri.org/IQueryRuleOperations/GetQueryParameterSpecification' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:2ffa95a4-0a71-4866-a3fb-2e33b6a0fe49'    b613bb9c-fc4a-a020-6d41-0a96138145fb

Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job SchedulingUnpublish). Execution Time=4.72553075879756    b613bb9c-3c4e-a020-6d41-01bfb551c3a0

Name=Timer Job TranslationExport    b613bb9c-bc4e-a020-6d41-04133823d269
```

TranslationExport has started   b613bb9c-bc4e-a020-6d41-04133823d269
****Unable to write service call usage entry**.**   b613bb9c-fc4a-a020-6d41-0a96138145fb

```
SearchServiceApplicationProxy::GetQueryParameterSpecification--Error occured: System.ServiceModel.Security.**SecurityAccessDeniedException: Access is denied**.    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at System.ServiceModel.Ch... b613bb9c-fc4a-a020-6d41-0a96138145fb

09/22/2014 13:30:04.01* w3wp.exe (0x2FEC)                           0x2CE8  SharePoint Server Search        Query                           dka5    High        ...annels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Rules.IQueryRuleOperations.GetQueryParameterSpecification(SearchObjectFilter filter)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoSpLoadBalancedUriWsOp[T](WebServiceBackedOperation`1 webServiceCall, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32 wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, String operationName) b613bb9c-fc4a-a020-6d41-0a96138145fb

QueryParameterCache::GetQueryParameters exception: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException: **Access is denied**.    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.... b613bb9c-fc4a-a020-6d41-0a96138145fb

09/22/2014 13:30:04.01* w3wp.exe (0x2FEC)                           0x2CE8  SharePoint Server Search        Query                           ajh4h   High        ...Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Rules.IQueryRuleOperations.GetQueryParameterSpecification(SearchObjectFilter filter)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoSpLoadBalancedUriWsOp[T](WebServiceBackedOperation`1 webServiceCall, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32 wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, String operationName)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoWebServiceBackedOperation[T](String operationName, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32 wcfTime...  b613bb9c-fc4a-a020-6d41-0a96138145fb

09/22/2014 13:30:04.01* w3wp.exe (0x2FEC)                           0x2CE8  SharePoint Server Search        Query                           ajh4h   High        ...outInMilliseconds, WebServiceBackedOperation`1 webServiceCall)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Utilities.QueryParameterCache.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetQueryParameters>b__0()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass5.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__3()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Utilities.QueryParameterCache.GetQueryParameters(Guid tenantId, Guid farmId, Guid siteId, Guid webId)   b613bb9c-fc4a-a020-6d41-0a96138145fb
```

I can manually access the endpoints in the browser.  We have tried using the setup/admin account, farm account, local administrators and domain administrator accounts.  Same results. I granted each of those same users access to the Search Service Application with Full Control.  Have rebuilt the Search Service a dozen times or so.  I've checked IIS to ensure that the endpoints were there on both WFE's and they were with security accounts provided access.

Comment: Might be "This is caused when the anonymous access account has been changed from IUSR."http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2892419

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I checked that and I already had the IUSR setting set for each of the web applications.  Just for good measure, I did re-set it and did an IISRESET just to be sure.  Still receiving the same Access Denied message.

Answer (score 1):

New farm, sounds like a permissions issue. Are you using service account for search? If so, that account shouldn't receive the error. I'd check the search service account permissions and make sure the account isn't locked out.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but whenever I've encountered such an error it was usually due to certificate issues. Given the errors you posted...

```
QueryParameterCache::GetQueryParameters exception: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException: **Access is denied**...
```

...I recommend checking that the certificates were properly created on all servers and have not expired. While I haven't setup 2013, in 2010 the certificate setup specifically for FAST Search was a bit convoluted and highly prone to errors.